# Powershell terminates early after exiting do-until loop

Tags: powershell, do-while, terminate

I'm working on a Powershell script, and I'm trying to accept custom user input from a list of options. The issue I'm running into is that when the exit condition (typing the character 'd') is met, the script terminates and does not execute the remaining code (which is supposed to copy shortcuts based on a user-defined array, $OfficeProgramNames)

```
#OfficeShortcuts -- Creates shortcuts for the main four Office 2016 applications.

#Optional command-line parameters that can be passed to create icons for All (-a) icons, or a CUSTOM set of icons (-c)
param([switch] $a, [switch] $c)

#Creates a shortcut on the desktop that copies from the start menu shortcuts.
function CreateOfficeDesktopShortcut([string] $ShortcutName)
{
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\$ShortcutName.lnk" "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop"
}

function Show-Menu
{
     Clear-Host
     Write-Host "Select which items you would like placed on the desktop:"

     Write-Host "1: Word"
     Write-Host "2: Excel"
     Write-Host "3: PowerPoint"
     Write-Host "4: Outlook"
     Write-Host "5: Access"
     Write-Host "6: OneNote"
     Write-Host "7: Publisher"
     Write-Host "D: Press 'D' when done."
}

function GetCustomUserSelection($OfficeProgramNames)
{
    $OfficeProgramNames = @()
    do
    {
        Clear-Host
        Show-Menu
        Write-Host "You have selected: $OfficeProgramNames"
        $foo = Read-Host "Please make a selection:"
        switch($foo)
        {
            '1'{
                $OfficeProgramNames += "Word*"
            }
            '2'{
                $OfficeProgramNames += "Excel*"
            }
            '3'{
                $OfficeProgramNames += "PowerPoint*"
            }
            '4'{
                $OfficeProgramNames += "Outlook*"
            }
            '5'{
                $OfficeProgramNames += "Access*"
            }
            '6'{
                $OfficeProgramNames += "OneNote*"
            }
            '7'{
                $OfficeProgramNames += "Publisher*"
            }
            '8'{
                $OfficeProgramNames += "Skype*"
            }
            'd'{
                return
            }
        }
    }
    until ($foo -eq 'd')
    Write-Host "Now do something else"
}

#Loop through the array of Shortcut names, and create a shortcut with a matching alias
function SelectOfficeShortcuts($arg1, $arg2)
{
    [string[]] $OfficeProgramNames = @("Word", "Excel", "PowerPoint", "Outlook")

    if ($a -eq $True)
    {
        $OfficeProgramNames += "Access", "OneNote*", "Publisher"
    }
    elseif($c -eq $True)
    {
        $OfficeProgramNames = @()
        GetCustomUserSelection $OfficeProgramNames
    }
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $OfficeProgramNames.Length; $i++)
    {
        CreateOfficeDesktopShortcut $OfficeProgramNames[$i]
    }
}

SelectOfficeShortcuts($a, $c)
```

I have tried inserting a couple of "Write-Host" commands to debug and see where the code stops terminating. I'm rather baffled and I'm having trouble seeing where the control flow is, so if someone could help me with some clarification, that would be greatly appreciated!

For further clarity, the output is as follows(slightly modified since there are some Clear-Host commands):

```
PS C:\Users\atroach\Documents\GitHub\OfficeShortcuts> .\OfficeShortcuts.ps1 -c

...

Select which items you would like placed on the desktop:
1: Word
2: Excel
3: PowerPoint
4: Outlook
5: Access
6: OneNote
7: Publisher
D: Press 'D' when done.
You have selected: Excel PowerPoint
Please make a selection: d
PS C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\OfficeShortcuts>
```

"SelectOfficeShortcuts ($a, $c)" is called at the end of the script, where $a and $c are switch parameters for the script.

Comment: Don't use `$input` its a reserved variable. Change that name

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have to call 'SelectOfficeShortcuts' before 'Write-Host "Exiting..."', and after your 'until' clause.

Comment: How do you call your functions? What are `$a` and `$c`

Comment: Apologies, I should have specified, the `SelectOfficeShortcuts` function is called as the last step in the script. `$a` and `$c` are switch parameters defined at the beginning of the script.

Comment: You probably wanted to use `break` instead of `return` to exit the switch,

Comment: using `break` seems to cause the do-until loop to repeat infinitely, regardless of whether or not I enter 'd'

Comment: Hmm that's strange, I literally copied your code and it exits properly. Perhaps I'm missing the whole context

Comment: Yeah, I feel like there is something going on in some of the other code that you have not shown...

Comment: Initial post has been edited to include the whole script.

Comment: Also changed `$input` to `$foo` @matt

Comment: You don't call PowerShell functions with parentheses: `SelectOfficeShortcuts($a, $c)`.  PowerShell treats this as if you're passing one item, an array with `$a` and `$c` as items.  Call like this: `SelectOfficeShortcuts $a $c` or even more clearly: `SelectOfficeShortcuts -arg1 $a -arg2 $c`